# How to load data on scroll to bottom in uitable from server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I want to load data from server on pull to refresh in my app.At the same time i want to implement the pull to refresh functionality.Please tell me how can i fetch data on pull to refresh.Should i use `WillDisplayCell` or `ScrollViewDelegate` method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below is what I do

```
if ((indexPath.row == yourArray.count - 1)) {
    [self methodNameHere];
}
return cell;
```

As per chat discussion, you want to add `indicator` at the bottom of the screen while loading the data... For that add indicator in one view and add that view as footer view for the table view. When loading of data is done, hide that remove footer view of table view.

Comment: where to write this code & how do i add uiactivity indicator for this?

Comment: @deepakkumar : write above return cell in `-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {`. using this when you go to last cell of the tableview, load more webservice will get call...

Comment: but i want to load when i scroll * add the loading symbol

Comment: @deepakkumar : write scrolling function before `[self methodNameHere];` Boss itna to pata hoga ke [indicator startAnimating] kaha likhneka...

Comment: This is my first implementing something like that. i am not abe to undestand how it will automatically added a bottom & gone way when new cells are added.

Comment: @deepakkumar : let me explain.. it will never go away... let's say one webservice call give you 10 items.. now while scrolling when you go to last cell, it will be if (9==10-1). now webservice will load more 10 items... now when you scroll more to last cell as per condiition it will be if(19==20-1). Now why 20 is because you have total of 20 items.. this way it will keep continuing...

Comment: @deepakkumar : go away where?? can you give me more details on exactly what u need?

Comment: i mean it should ne hidden .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92961/discussion-between-fahim-parkar-and-deepak-kumar).

Comment: @deepakkumar : come in chat

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve following below tutorials. Same logic Also work for UITableview and UICollectionView.

Reference Link:

http://www.iosnomad.com/blog/2014/4/21/fluent-pagination

**Logic For Collection view Into Add Cell After Scrolling Last Cell:**

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView{


        for (UICollectionViewCell *cell in [self.collectionView visibleCells]) {

            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:cell];
            NSUInteger lastIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition:[indexPath length] - 1];

            //Add Section Delete Cell Perform Here
            // NSInteger upComingSectionVal;
            //NSMutableArray * array_data;

                if(indexPath.section == (upComingSectionVal-1) && (lastIndex == ([array_data[upComingSectionVal-1][@"Data"] count]))) {

                    [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{

                        NSIndexPath *indexPath =[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([array_data[upComingSectionVal-1][@"Data"] count]) inSection:(upComingSectionVal-1)];
                        [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]];

                        [self.collectionView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:upComingSectionVal]];

                        upComingSectionVal = upComingSectionVal+1;

                    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                        [self.collectionView reloadData];
                        //  nil;
                    }];

                    break;
                }


            }

}
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: it would be great if you put relevant code with link instead of link for following tuts...

Comment: @FahimParkar, I have implemented same thing using following tutorial. I am not able to share code with you due to privacy issues. Tutorial into all things explain very nicely. Do some stuff own way. Thanks!

Comment: I would say why you are asking user to click Load More button? just call the webservice with new page index and append it to current array when you reach to last cell... asking user continuously pressing Load More is part of **bad design** *move to new world, don't stay for long time what was being followed old days*

Comment: @FahimParkar, Yes you are definitely Right. It is old design pattern. You should automatically call webservice and load data automatically When Last cell/Row display. You should easily insert Row/Cell Runtime dynamically.

Comment: @FahimParkar, Please review my edit answer and let us know ur comments. Thank you so much!

Comment: thank you for the good words. If you can, don't play with scrollViewDidEndDecelerating for checking last cell... just write three lines of code (check my answer) to check whether you reached last cell of tableview or not and call the webservice there.. that's it...

Answer (score 0):

There is **UIRefreshControl** that is used for pull to refresh purpose

A peace of code how to implement in your view did load

```
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)

func refresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
// Do your job, when done:
refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

For infinite Scrolling use this library

https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh

```
[tableView addInfiniteScrollingWithActionHandler:^{
// append data to data source, insert new cells at the end of table view
// call [tableView.infiniteScrollingView stopAnimating] when done
}];
```

It will help.Thanks

Comment: That will not scroll to bottom

Comment: i doubt apple reject app to third party api use

Comment: I used in in alot of my apps and they all are live now. . .third party library is to help and to minimize our workload

Comment: ok thanks .But how to be sure which third party lib will wok or not

Comment: I have mention the link above

Answer (score 0):

You can try SVPullToRefresh pod:
https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh